# Kentico CMS Friendly Url Wildcard With Multiple Parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, friendly-url, kentico

I have a page within my Kentico site that will be used to filter results based on parameters within the URL.

I setup a wildcard within my "Document URL Path" settings on my search page to be the following:

/Search/{tags}

So the full URL would be:

http://www.mysite.com/Search/SearchTag1

However, this only works with one search parameter. I would like to be able to have a nice clean URL with multiple search tags similar to StackOverflow:

http://www.mysite.com/Search/SearchTag1+SearchTag2+SearchTag3

But I cannot seem to achieve this. If I structure my URL with multiple tags, I get a 404 page.

Is the only way around this is to create *x* number of wildcards in my Url in my page properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I believe I found the answer. Out of the box, Kentico disallows plus signs in its URL's as stated here: http://devnet.kentico.com/Forums/f55/fp3/t25532/Plus-Signs-in-url-do-not-work.aspx.

To get around this, you can choose what symbols you want disallowed from the URL by creating a new appsetting in your web.config called: "CMSForbiddenURLValues". More information on this can be found in Kentico's knowledge base: http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/index.html?url_format_and_configuration.htm

In the end, I decided to split my keywords with hyphen's instead of plus signs and this resolved the 404 page issue.